# How to limit the imports (importURI) to certain file type

Tags: xtext

I'm trying to impose some Import limitations. I have 2 DSLs (let's say dsl1 and dsl1). I do have import mechanism, which is working fine (importURI), and I just need somehow to validate the imported resource. 
At this point in dsl2 I can import both dsl1 and dsl2 - but the I would like to be able to get imported (restrict to) only dsl1 extension.

Comment: any reason not to write a simple validator?

Comment: hmm, what do you mean by "write simple validator"? I just need to be able to import only one type of resource...otherwise I would have to do more complex checks...

Comment: you can simply add a validator to your MyDslVaidator that checks the importURI

Comment: Yes, I just don't know how do I get from importURI the type of resource...could you help me with this please?

Comment: In the worst case I could check only for extension...but I don't like this solution...It would be better if I could somehow load the resource and check if it is of certain type - and I didn't find any examples on how to load resources manually from importURI :(

Comment: why load the resource

Comment: you could e.g. implement the scope provider and wrap the default scope `delegateGetScope(context,ref)` into a `FilteringScope` and check the `IEObjectDescription`s EObjectURI